# Convert richtextbox text into a stream c#

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox control in a C# winform application which contains formatted data (bold, italicized, underlined, center aligned etc). I want to load this formatted text present in the richtextbox to a Stream in C# without losing the formatting.

Currently, when I get the data from richtextbox to a stream, the formatting information is being lost and not present in the stream. 
Any advise/inputs on how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format would the data in the `Stream` be? Perhaps you should ask about what you're **actually** trying to do, instead of focusing on the `Stream` part. Classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Jonathon The data in the Stream will be in rtf format. I want to get the byte stream of the formatted text present in the richtextbox. Thank you.

Comment: The control has a [RTF property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.71).aspx) and a [SaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(v=vs.71).aspx) method. I think the question remains, though. What is your intent?

Comment: I would like to perform byte conversion operation depending on each byte of data in the stream. For this, I need to get the data present in the richtextbox to a Stream without losing the formatting information. I know to get the data in the richtextbox to a stream, but I'm losing the formatting once it is in the stream.

Comment: the text itself is that a string. adding that strings tags like in HTML will save the format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Zec**  said, you can use RTF property 
`var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(richTextBox1.Rtf));`